# Unstable network connection, port 41112

Tags: internet, internet-connection, port

I have a problem with stability of my internet connection. I use a router for my home LAN (Asus WL-500gP V2). Recently, i've seen there are many "denied" log entries so i thought maybe the problem is that the router breaks connection or drops too many packets. The log looks like this:

```
Nov 13 20:15:16  filter: TCP connection denied to MyRoutersIp:41112 from WeirdIp1:4882
Nov 13 20:15:16  filter: UDP connection denied to MyRoutersIp:41112 from WeirdIp2:41996
Nov 13 20:15:17  filter: TCP connection denied to MyRoutersIp:41112 from WeirdIp3:2551
Nov 13 20:15:19  filter: TCP connection denied to MyRoutersIp:41112 from WeirdIp1:62908
```

It always is a port 41112, packets are udp/tcp and come from different IPs (whois suggests amsterdam, asia and so on). I've found something about Linux, Cluster Nodes and CLX distro on Google, but i just don't understand, why these packets are send to me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely they are just machines infected with a virus out there that are probing out. Typically if you notify your ISP's abuse team, your ISP notifies their ISP's abuse team and their ISP warns them to fix it or disables their connection. This is very very common.